# Side pot with fold

Tags: side-pots

Player A all in for 40
Player B raise to   80
Player C raise to  200
Player B fold
Player A wins hand

Player A would get 120 ?
Player C would get 200 ?

Just checking?
Is there some weird logic that B folded to C so C gets all of B?

Player C wins they get the whole pot ?

Comment: If player B has a better hand than A, can B still win the main pot after folding from aide pot!?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The logic is that you can't win more against any other player than you bet, and when you fold you forfeit all bets you have made into the pot.  For any given pot the best (or last, if everyone else has folded) hand that has an interest in that pot (has money in it and hasn't folded) wins that pot.  Your amounts of 120 and 200 are correct. To break it down:

Player A all in for 40.

Player B raises to 80.  Main pot 40(A)+40(B), side pot has 40(B).

Player C raises to 200. Main pot 40(A)+40(B)+40(C), side pot has 40(B)+160(C).

Player B folds, forfeiting side pot of 200 to B. (A does not have an interest in this side pot.)

Player A wins at showdown, and gets main pot of 120.

Comment: I think this is correct but will give it a couple days before giving it the check just in case someone has a different opinion.

Answer (score -1):

Person A wins with the main pot and gets 120 points or chips

Comment: This adds nothing new that wasn't already in the accepted answer.